# How can I calculate the geometric center of a protein in Perl?

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I have a PDB file which contains information about a specific protein. One of the information it holds is the positions of the different atoms (xyz coordinates).

The file is the following https://files.rcsb.org/view/6U9D.pdb . With this file I want to calculate the geometric center of the atoms. In theory I know what I need to do, but the script I wrote does not seem to work.

The first part of the program, before the for loop, is another part of the assignment which requires me to read the sequence and convert it from the 3 letter nomenclature to the 1 letter one. The part that interests me is the for loop until the end. I tried to pattern match in order to isolate the XYZ coordinates. Then I used a counter that I had set up in the beginning which is the `$k` variable. When I check the output on cygwin the only output I get is the sequence `0 0 0` instead of the sum of each dimension divided by `$k`. Any clue what has gone wrong?

```
$k=0;   
open (IN, '6U9D.pdb.txt');
%amino_acid_conversion = (
   ALA=>'A',TYR=>'Y',MET=>'M',LEU=>'L',CYS=>'C',
   GLY=>'G',ARG=>'R',ASN=>'N',ASP=>'D',GLN=>'Q',
   GLU=>'E',HIS=>'H',TRP=>'W',LYS=>'K',PHE=>'F',
   PRO=>'P',SER=>'S',THR=>'T',ILE=>'I',VAL=>'V'
);
while (<IN>) {
   if ($_=~m/HEADER\s+(.*)/){
   print ">$1\n"; }
   if ($_=~m/^SEQRES\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+(.*)/){
       $seq.=$1;
       $seq=~s/ //g;
   }
}

for ($i=0;$i<=length $seq; $i+=3) {
   print "$amino_acid_conversion{substr($seq,$i,3)}";      
   if ($_=~m/^ATOM\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/) {
       $x+=$1; $y+=$2; $z+=$3; $k++;
   }
}
print "\n";
#print $k;
$xgk=($x/$k); $ygk=($y/$k); $zgk=($z/$k);
print "$xgk $ygk $zgk \n";
```

Comment: Please provide the inputs (file) necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Also, you should ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. It catches so many errors.

Comment: What do you think `$_` contains in the for loop?

Comment: @ikegami *Please provide the inputs (file) necessary to demonstrate the problem*  There's a link to it in the question.

Comment: Well I have linked the input file. I'm pretty sure ```$_``` is supposed to be the contents of the input file

Comment: I didn't ask what it's supposed to contain

Comment: I think it has the contents of the file I have inserted

Comment: You think? Have you checked?

Comment: I noticed that the for loop was not included in the ```while```. I tried to include it but the result was that it kept printing out the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know bioinformatics but it seems like you should do something like this:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = '6U9D.pdb';
open ( my $IN, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $seq = '';
my $x = 0;
my $y = 0;
my $z = 0;
my $k = 0;
while (<$IN>) {
   if ($_ =~ m/HEADER\s+(.*)/) {
       say ">$1";
   }
   if ($_=~m/^SEQRES\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+(.*)/){
       $seq .= $1;
   }
   if ($_ =~ m/^ATOM\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/) {
       $x+=$1; $y+=$2; $z+=$3; $k++;
   }
}
close $IN;
$seq =~ s/ //g;
my %amino_acid_conversion = (
   ALA=>'A',TYR=>'Y',MET=>'M',LEU=>'L',CYS=>'C',
   GLY=>'G',ARG=>'R',ASN=>'N',ASP=>'D',GLN=>'Q',
   GLU=>'E',HIS=>'H',TRP=>'W',LYS=>'K',PHE=>'F',
   PRO=>'P',SER=>'S',THR=>'T',ILE=>'I',VAL=>'V'
);
my %unknown_keys;
my $conversion = '';
say "Sequence length: ", length $seq;
for (my $i=0; $i < length $seq; $i += 3) {
    my $key = substr $seq, $i, 3;
    if (exists $amino_acid_conversion{$key}) {
        $conversion.= $amino_acid_conversion{$key};
    }
    else {
        $unknown_keys{$key}++;
    }
}
say "Conversion: $conversion";
say "Unknown keys: ", join ",", keys %unknown_keys;
say "Number of atoms: ", $k;
my $xgk=($x/$k);
my $ygk=($y/$k);
my $zgk=($z/$k);
say "Geometric center: $xgk $ygk $zgk";
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[...]
Number of atoms: 76015
Geometric center: 290.744642162734 69.196842162731 136.395842938893
```